# Microsoft Certification Authority: How to make certificates work on domain active directory

Tags: windows-server-2012, certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, ssl-certificate-errors

I have been struggling with Microsoft Certification Authority lately.

Most resources only explain how SSL works and what certificates are, how they work, how they are issued and what they are used for. 
I understand all of that now.

Thanks to another users help I was able to sign HP ILO certificates successfully. The problem was that this still hasn't solved the certificate error.

The Error:

```
The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
```

Even the CA-Server has this error. `https://ipofCA-server/certsrv/`

Is there something I have missed? Or how to approach this issue correctly?

Comment: It's in the message. The certificate Subject CN does not match the url. As you have not provided the url or certificate Subject are, or if you made an attempt to ensure they match, probably not much we can help with.

Comment: @GregAskew how do I create a certificate whose CN does match the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Baltimore root certificate.
"Baltimore Cyber Trust" certificate must be into your trusted.

If you are on android go to /settings/security/certificate managment

If you use windows run mmc , then add local and user certificate from top menu/add, install certificate cer personal store and trusted regarding local and user stores. Then give permission of certificate and restart browser.

Then you need to check CN in your certificate. Must be equal to domain name. For example CN=*.live.com